# 503 Service Unavailable, PHP 5.3 Web App

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

My PHP wordpress app ([reversiblean-reversiblean.rhcloud.com](http://reversiblean-reversiblean.rhcloud.com/)) returns HTTP Error **'503 Service Unavailable, No server is available to handle this request.'**, ongoing for 1d 22h

I haven't made any changes recently.

I've already tried,

`rhc app restart -a reversiblean`

```
rhc app force-stop -a reversiblean
rhc app start -a reversiblean
```

`ctl_app restart`

.. without any success.

[image: haproxy-status]

`rhc tail` constantly returns,

> [error] [client 127.7.77.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pp_popup_id() in > /var/lib/openshift/5294c322597.../app-root/data/wp-content/themes/clean-retina/footer.php on line 62

Comment: Probably plugin is missing - http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2014/05/13/popunder-popup-wordpress-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're missing the `pp_popup_id()` function, which should be defined by the [Popunder Popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popunder-popup/) Wordpress plugin. Make sure you have this plugin installed.

Comment: Deleting `pp_popup_id()` function call from footer.php and clearing the cache did the trick.